# How to disable focus stealing in GNOME 3.30.2 on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, x11, gnome

Basically the header - I can no longer tolerate windows popping up under my mouse pointer while I wait for the applications to load. I tried the solutions for Ubuntu with Compiz, but it had zero effect on my system. Bonus question - are there any desktop environments that allow reliably disabling focus stealing?